# Use 24 AWG to jump LED strip tape?

Tags: voltage

I have 12 V LED strip tape, actually running with a 9 volt source. I need to use a short amount of wire to connect two strips. I've seen some people use 22 AWG stranded, but I would prefer to use 24 AWG if possible. We're talking about 6 inches or so. Would it work okay?

Comment: I would recommend to use AWG26, my general purpose wiring standard for "light duty" applications. If you are serious or slightly worrying, you can check out the AWG spec and the 12V LED strip spec.

Comment: I would recommend this AWG guide: Wire Gauge and Current Limits Including Skin Depth and Tensile Strength July 13, 2022
https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Comment: You may like to give us the link to your 12V LED strip.

Comment: You might find my answer to this Q&A useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563073/led-lighting-for-use-in-miniature-tanks

Comment: And this is a tutorial for 12V LED strip newbies: LED-strip-light-schematic-and-voltage-information
https://www.waveformlighting.com/pcb-designs/led-strip-light-schematic-and-voltage-information

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me. Here's the link: https://www.ledwholesalers.com/v2/index.php?route=product/product&path=39_81_97&product_id=1134&filter=1

Comment: I think the entire roll needs 48 watts. I use it to illuminate models. I have a 35 inch plastic model and I use strips about 8 inches long. In one section I need to run wires from an arduino board to the strip. I like using wire from a ribbon cable cuz it so light weight. I said 24awg cuz my stripper setting works great at that gauge. But it might be smaller. Im hoping that running an 8 inch pair from the board to the strip will be fine.

Comment: Btw Wikipedia says ribbon cable is 24 or 26 gauge. Mine looks like 26.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138358/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-coreysan).